# Time Complexity Analysis Using Big (O)

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, big-o, slice

```
arr = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
total = 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    total += sum(arr[i:])
```

Is the time complexity for the above code is O(n^2) or O(n^3), the confusion because of the slicing of the list arr. So how does slicing arr effects the time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Slicing a list is `O(k)` with `k` being the size of the slice, which in this case rounds up to `O(n)`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). However, in this case, the time complexity is still `O(n^2)`, because `arr[i:]` is additive with `sum()`, not multiplicative. We can see this if we decompose it into two separate steps:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):        # executes n times
    things_to_sum_over = arr[i:]      # runs in (k -> n) time
    total += sum(things_to_sum_over)  # operates over (k -> n) elements
```

This gives a total  `n * 2(k -> n)`, or `2n^2` = `O(n^2)`.